# Suggestions for a multiple socket design (Android)

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

I'm trying to think of a way to implement an app that:

-Opens up x amount of sockets (User specified)
-Each socket can remain open for the lifetime of the application and continues running in the background
-Creates multiple Activities of the same layout, each would be used to display information received from a socket.

Currently I have an implementation that takes sends/receives from one socket.  A service runs in background to continue processing information from the socket, and then sends it to an activity.  However, my current train of thought leads me to believe that I'd need one service for each socket open to continue processing it in the background.  I'm fairly new to Android so some clarification would be great.

Thanks

Comment: This is very generic question so without some context of why you think you need multiple sockets and multiple activities we can't really assess if this is the right thing or not.  Describe your actual problem then we can judge if this path makes any sense.  I'm pretty sure you don't need an activity/socket, and that the activit(ies) can be parameterized to be told which socket they should display.  But don't want to jump the gun too much.  Why would the user specify how many sockets to open?

Comment: It's for connecting to multiple chat servers.  One "user" per server, so if they wanted to open up 2 users, they would need two separate connections.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a single service that manages all socket connections.  Services are defined in your AndroidManifest so as a consequence you can't run multiple services of the same type, and you can't create services at runtime (by that you can't define new services at runtime).  So you're stuck with using a single service.  That doesn't mean you can't have multiple instances of a Class that represent each connection to a server.  In fact that's exactly what I'd recommend, but those instances won't be Android Services.

Its something of the same thing for Activities.  You can't really create multiple instances of an Activity at the same time.  Android plays lots of tricks to make it appear that way, but in reality its either always the same instance you had last time, or that one is gone and here is a new one.  But, at one time there is only ever one instance of an Activity.  So you'll have to make do with those limitations, but they are there for your own good to keep you from using up tons of memory.

Now, that means you Activity that displays a chat session will have to be flexible so that it can be parameterized by which session it should be displaying.  That can easily be done with an intent extra parameter.  For example:

```
public void openSession( ChatSession session ) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( getContext(), ChatSessionActivity.class )
         .putExtra( ChatSessionActivity.PARAM_CHAT_SESSION_ID, session.getID() );
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

And that's how another Activity might navigate the user to the ChatSession like say picking from a list of chat sessions.  In your activity you'd look at the intent passed to onCreate(), and connect to the service, then query the service for the ChatSession.  You'll have to have a mechanism to allow the ChatSessionActivity to register and unregister itself with the service to get updates.  That could be through using BroadcastReceivers, register listeners, Messages, etc.  There's a whole host of options.  For example:

```
public void onServiceConnected() {
   ChatSession session = service.getSession( sessionId );
   session.setChatListener( this );
}

public void onStart() {
    if( service.isConnected() ) session.setChatListener(this);
}

public void onStop() {
   session.setChatListener( null );
}
```

Anyway, those are just some simple ideas on how to structure your program.

Answer (score 0):

I would use just one service. Please remember that even if you run your code inside a service, you will need to perform all the network related operations inside a separate thread / asynctask, or you will end up freezing the ui thread.

If I were you, I would give a look at [java nio framework](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/), which is available in android too. It should make easier to open / manage many connections.

Regarding the activities, I would just use one activity (I mean, one activity class), to be differentiated according to the connection it refers to.

Finally, don't forget that you have limited resources on a phone. Opening several sockets (and moreover, keeping them connected in background) could result in a battery drain.

You should warn the user that your app will keep running in background and, for example, notify it with a notification icon whenever your app is backgrounded.